# Mocking function in Prometheus Rule Unit Test

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I am struggling to create a unit test for my alert rule.

Our rule:
round(sum(increase(counter_total{cluster="prod",service="xxx"}[1h])),1) == 0 and (hour()) < 16 > 7

The goal of the rule is to alert us when the counter is zero, for at least one hour, between working hours.

Now I would like to write a unit test for this but I am having trouble to mock the hour function. I cannot find a tutorial or anything that might help to write a test.

I hope someone can help me with this as I am out of ideas.